# Date format JSON jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, json, jqgrid

I'm developing a web application in java. I'm filling a jqgrid with JSON data. The problem is that the column "birthdate" shows an incorrect format. In MySQL database the field is `DATE` type, but in the jqgrid it is shown as: "Dec 30, 1989". I need the following format: '1989-12-30'

My servlet code:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String parameter = request.getParameter("parameter");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    int option = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("option"));

    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Connection con = (Connection) db.getCon();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Customers> customerList = new ArrayList<Customers>();

    try {
        sb.append("{call SP_MSTCUSTOMERS_FIND(?,?,?)}");
        ps = con.prepareCall(sb.toString());
        ps.setString(1, parameter);
        ps.setString(2, username);
        ps.setInt(3, option);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Customers customer = new Customers();
            customer.setIdMstCustomers(rs.getInt("IDMSTCUSTOMERS"));
            customer.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            customer.setLastName(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
            customer.setBirthdate(rs.getDate("BIRTHDATE"));       
            customerList.add(customer);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(customerList, new TypeToken<List<Customers>>() {
    }.getType());

    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
}
```

The jqgrid's code:

```
 $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'PopulateCustomersTable',
    postData: {
        parameter: function () {
            return $("#parameter").val();
        },
        username: function () {
            return $("#txtusrID").val();
        },
        option: function () {
            return $("input[name='srch']:checked").val(); //$('[name="srch"]').val();
        }
    },
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Birthdate'],
    colModel: [{
            name: 'IdMstCustomers',
            index: 'IdMstCustomers',
            width: 50,
            fixed: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            name: 'FirstName',
            index: 'FirstName',
            width: 100,
            fixed: true,
            align: 'center',
            editable: true
        }, {
            name: 'LastName',
            index: 'LastName',
            width: 100,
            fixed: true,
            align: 'center',
            editable: true
        }, {
            name: 'Birthdate',
            index: 'Birthdate',
            width: 100,
            editable: true,                
        }],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'FirstName',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Customers',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    editurl: "CustomersServlet"
});
$('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridWidth', '900'); 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    edit: true,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: true
});
```

[The jqgrid data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zDCt.png)

My customers class

```
public Customers(int IdMstCustomers, String FirstName, String LastName, Date Birthdate) {
    this.setIdMstCustomers(IdMstCustomers);
    this.setFirstName(FirstName);
    this.setLastName(LastName);
    this.setBirthdate(Birthdate);
}

public Customers() {

}
private int IdMstCustomers;
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private Date Birthdate;

public void setIdMstCustomers(int IdMstCustomers) {
    this.IdMstCustomers = IdMstCustomers;
}

public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}

public void setLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}

public void setBirthdate(Date Birthdate) {
    this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
}

public int getIdMstCustomers() {
    return IdMstCustomers;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public Date getBirthdate() {
    return Birthdate;
}
```

Comment: Please post your source JSON data not the data shown in the jqGrid. Also some other note:  the command `$('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');` is absolutely not needed to be run - with this one you reloads the grid once again when it is build, but nothing is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `formatter` to format the date value as per your required format:

```
{
    name: 'Birthdate',
    index: 'Birthdate',
    width: 100,
    editable: true,
    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'M, d, Y', newformat: 'Y-m-d'}
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Comment: Didn't work for me, still shows an incorrect format: 70707070-JanJan-0101

Comment: Thank you @Waqas! Worked for me with a very small adjustment: formatoptions: { srcformat: 'M d, Y', newformat: 'Y-m-d'} the comma after the M of month part was the problem

Comment: Nice, could you please mark it as a correct answer then? Thanks